# batch with a lot of for loops

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

So i made this batch to psarc extract all *.pak files, which will always give *.mbin files that often have the same name. it's then supposed to look for all extracted subfolders and then look for the last created *.mbin file from all of the subfolders and rename it to its current name plus a number. but i get  very weird results.

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set number=0
cd /d "C:\Users\storm\Desktop\No Man's Sky\GAMEDATA\PCBANKS\MODS"
for /r %%f in (*.pak=) do (
    psarcMBIN.exe extract %%~nxf
    set /A number=!number!+1 
    FOR /F "tokens=" %%a in ('dir /a:d /s') do (
        cd /d "%%a"
        FOR /F "tokens=" %%G in ('dir /b /a:-d /o:d "*.mbin"') do set newest=%%G
        rename "!newest!" "!newest!!number!.mbin"
    )   
)
pause
```

The result basically is just:
1. psarc extracted
2. psarc tried to extract next file but cannot overwrite

The other parts of the main for loop are not even shown

Comment: You should tell us what "weird results" you get; please provide sample data...

Comment: Perhaps an example of the 'weird results' and explanation of how it differs from your expectation would be prudent. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51725638/edit) to add that information.

Comment: You are assigning the file name without the extension to the variable newest. The rename will fail because of that. It will not find the file you are trying to rename.

Comment: Also, %~nxf is the file name with extension. Any files that the FOR command finds in a sub-folder will not be extracted because it will not find the file in the current working directory.